# Rails: Difference between declaring a route directly inside the `resources` block vs. enclosing it with a `member` block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, router

What's the difference between the `/animals/:animal_id/info(.:format)` and `/animals/:id/info(.:format)` routes in the following, except parameter names? And why are the parameter names different?

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :animals do
    get 'info'

    member do
      get 'info'
    end
  end
end
```

`~/myrails>rails routes`

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
  animal_info GET    /animals/:animal_id/info(.:format) animals#info
  info_animal GET    /animals/:id/info(.:format)        animals#info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if we write the `member` block or directly write the get routes inside the `resources` both are considered as member routes.

Its the rails convention to differentiate between both of the routes. If we write the member block it is considered that all the routes declared within that block are declared from the member block explicitly.

```
resources :animals do
    member do
      get 'info'
    end
end

info_animal GET    /animals/:id/info(.:format)    animals#info
```

But if we directly declare `get` or other routes inside the `resources` block this will **also** create the same `member` route except that the `resource id` value will be available in `params[:animal_id]` instead of `params[:id]`. Route helpers will also be renamed from `info_animal_url` and `info_animal_path` to `animal_info_url` and `animal_info_path`. I think this is to make difference that request is not coming from the `member` block.

```
resources :animals do
    get 'info'
end

animal_info GET    /animals/:animal_id/info(.:format)    animals#info
```

If we write `get` route with the `on:` option with value `:member` inside the resources directly then this will be treated same as the member block route

```
resources :animals do
    get 'info', on: :member
end

info_animal GET    /animals/:id/info(.:format)    animals#info
```

Comment: " I think this is to make difference that request is not coming from the member block.". Yea that makes sense when you consider how nested resources work.